# Drupal views 2 API

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I would like to create a custom views, because some database fields are not accessible by drupal views UI. I just exported an existing view into a file called my_module_views_default.inc that contains the hook_views_default_views() function. and by the drupal views2 document state that the hook gets called automatically, but it doesn't. 
Also i want to know the path, we are giving the path in the code here

## $handler->override_option('path', 'my_earnings');

That means we can see the views in the link http://localhost/drupal6/my_earnings ??

and
in my .module file, i use the hook_views_api as follows

```
function mymodule_views_api() {
```

return array(
    'api' => 2,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_earnings'),
  );
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the document [Using default views in your module](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-default-views)  and i created a new module, and i exporting a existing view. Then i placing my exported views into new module in file **mymodule.views_default.inc**. My views should now be listed as Overridden on the view list page and clear the Views cache. Revert these views, they will be removed from the database, but will remain in code.

Thanks alot to all..

Answer (score 0):

I was caught with the same issue where i needed to join the two table in view. fortunately i found these links

http://drupalmodules.com/module/reverse-node-reference module enhances views with reverse relationships for node reference fields.

you may also need http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships

Using these module i don't think we need any custom module writing for view.